# Is there any solution for "n --- property 'topology' closes the circle" in Postman while working with nodejs and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I'm writing the code in nodeJS for getting the user from MongoDB.When I sent the request http://localhost:5000/api/users in Postman, I ran into an error. I have seen a similar problem but all the answers are about the addObject, toObject and constructors in Javascript.I have used toObject and error is not about the "toObject" method. Here is my code,

```
const getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  let users;
  try {
    users = User.find({}, '-password');
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'fetching user failed',
      500);
      return next(error);
  }
  res.json({users: users.map(user=> user.toObject({ getters: true}))})

};
```

Here is the full error message as it is not allowed to write more than 150 characters in the question box:

{
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle"
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

it was occuring because i was not using async await. any mongoose operation like find() findOne, etc returns a promise and to get the proper data you should resolve it using .then(), .catch() or async await.

Answer (score 3):

This statement was the life saver:

> You must catch errors that occur in **asynchronous code** invoked by route handlers or middleware and pass them to Express for processing.

```
const getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  let users;
  try {
    users = await User.find({}, '-password');
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Fetching users failed, please try again later.',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
  res.json({users: users.map(user => user.toObject({ getters: true }))});
};
```

It worked! After hours of searching i solved it. Also, if someone still gets stuck this is the resource http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html where you can find answers of so many questions while working with express and nodejs.